# "Can't locate Fcntl.pm in @INC" error running "sensors-detect" on Yocto

Tags: perl, yocto, lm-sensors

I am using Yocto, and as per my project requirement I need to include `lmsensors` package in yocto image. I have included `lmsensors` package, and I am able to run `sensors` command but get following errors while running `sensors-detect`:

```
Can't locate Fcntl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Fcntl module)
   (@INC contains:
   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1/i686-linux
   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.28.1
   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28.1/i686-linux
   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.28.1
   /usr/lib/perl5/5.28.1/i686-linux
   /usr/lib/perl5/5.28.1
   .) at /usr/sbin/sensors-detect line 26.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/sbin/sensors-detect line 26.
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

When I try to find `Fcntl.pm` module, I can see it is present here `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.28.1/x86_64-linux/Fcntl.pm`.

Questions?

- Why `sensors-detect` doesn't look into `lib64` and only look into `lib`(32 bit) folders?
- Why `32 bit` Fcntl.pm is not getting generated?
- How to resolve above error?

**Edit:**
I am using `multilib` in machine config. Can it cause this issue?

```
require conf/multilib.conf                                                                                                                                         
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "corei7-32"
```

Comment: You appear to using a 32-bit perl. `/usr/lib64/perl5/5.28.1/x86_64-linux/Fcntl.pm` was installed by a different `perl` (a 64-bit `perl`); it's not relevant. As to why your 32-bit perl doesn't have Fcntl? That should never happen.

Comment: Apparently the `Fcntl` module is an XS module that is installed when `perl` itself is installed (I guess then it cannot be installed later as an addon). Here is a [link](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/tree/blead/ext/Fcntl) to the source. The best chance to make your scripts work is then to switch to the 64 bit version of `perl` which appears to have the `Fcntl` module installed